# Unable to transform edge error when clipping ImageCollection in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, clip, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, modis, evi

I am attempting to clip an ImageCollection in GEE, but I keep getting the error

> "Unable to transform edge (43200.000000, 1.476288 to 43200.000000,
> 1.477361) from SR-ORG:6974 PLANAR [926.625433055833, 0.0, -2.0015109354E7, 0.0, -926.6254330558334, 1.0007554677003E7] to EPSG:4326."

Below is my code that I am working with. The main function (evi) obtains the necessary images and returns a list of images, each with a number of bands. The list is then cast to an ImageCollection, which I then try to clip using the last function (us_clip). The clip returns the error noted above. In testing, when I use us_clip on an ImageCollection that hasn't been through the evi function below, it is successful.

Can you provide some guidance on clipping the resulting ImageCollection?

````
var geompoly = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[-130.2328, 52.851],
          [-63.6722, 52.851],
          [-63.6722, 21.7423],
          [-130.2328, 21.7423]]], null, false);
          
var myList = ee.List.sequence(1,12);                       //months

function evi(month){
  //get mask images
  var modis_mask = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/061/MOD13A2') //modis terra 16-day mask
  .select('SummaryQA')                                     //select mask band
  .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(2009,2018,'year'))       //filter for years 2009-2018
  .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(month, month, 'month'))  //filter on month
  .toBands()                                               //imgcoll -> image
  .eq(0);                                                  //0 = Good data, Use with confidence
  
  //get evi images
  var modis_evi = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/061/MOD13A2') //modis terra 16-day evi
  .select('EVI')                                          //select evi band
  .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(2009,2018,'year'))      //filter for years 2009-2018
  .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(month, month, 'month')) //filter on month
  .toBands()                                              //imgcoll -> image
  .updateMask(modis_mask);                                //mask lesser quality pixels
  
  var bands = modis_evi.bandNames();                      //get band names
  
  //function to go from image w/ bands -> list of images
  function bands2imglst(bandnames) {
  return modis_evi.select([bandnames]);
  }
  var list = bands.map(bands2imglst);                     //create list of images

  var collection = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(list)    //list of images -> imgcoll
    .toBands();                                           //imgcoll -> img w/ bands
 
  return(collection);
}

//execute function
var modis_evi_result = myList.map(evi);                    //returns list of images w/ bands

var modis_evi_coll = ee.ImageCollection(modis_evi_result); //list -> image collection
print(modis_evi_coll);

//funtion to clip images w/in imgcoll
function us_clip(imgcol) {
  var manip_img = imgcol.clip(geompoly);
  return manip_img;
}  
var clipped = modis_evi_coll.map(us_clip);
print(clipped);```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be a bug, but you can work around it by clipping the individual images before you call `toBands`:

```
  var modis_evi = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/061/MOD13A2')
    .select('EVI')
    .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(2009,2018,'year'))
    .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(month, month, 'month'))
    .map(function(img) {
      return img.clip(geompoly)
    })
    .toBands()
    .updateMask(modis_mask)
```